# Creating Custom 'Buy Now' button with Custom buy now link

Tags: magento-1.9, affiliate

I'm trying to create an affiliate website using Magento so I'd like to add 'Buy Now' button replacing 'Add to Cart' button. Also, I should be able to provide custom link of the product from the backend.

Ex. If I'm affiliate of Amazon, I should be able to provide the link of the product from Amazon in the backend of my Magento store so that when customer clicks on buy now button, they are redirected to that page of Amazon/Any website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create product text attribute to store some affiliate link
2. Update `template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` or add your own template for the «Buy Now» button
3. Update `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` with your button
4. Check affiliate attribute and use its content in href or onClick attribute of your element

Please, show what have you already tried and what issues appear.